# stream was reset: PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: model-view-controller, http-post

I've written a web API for sending and receiving data between a server and an app I'm working on.

It works fine for everything, but I've now found it won't let me send large strings. The strings are base64 strings which represent images, typically around 100kb in size.

The method I'm attempting is a multipart post, breaking the base64 string into chunks that can be sent successfully.

When I use this method, I get an error:

> stream was reset: PROTOCOL_ERROR

Upon checking the database it seems the first string chunk sends successfully, but nothing more after that.

Can anyone shed some light on what's causing this to happen?

Relevant code is here:

First is the process for breaking the image into manageable chunks and posting it:

```
HTTPRequest req = new HTTPRequest();

IEnumerable<string> imgStrSplit = Split(img1byteArrayStr, 1000);

                    foreach (string s in imgStrSplit)
                    {
                        response = await req.SubmitImage("Test", s, "1");
                    }
```

And below is the SubmitImage() method of the HTTPRequest class:

```
public async Task<int> SubmitImage(string name, string imageString, string imgNum)
        {

            using (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

                int successResponse;

                string address = $"https://myURL/SubmitImage?name=" + name + "&imageStr=" + imageString + "&imgNum=" + imgNum + "&curl=AYZYBAYZE143";

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(address);

                successResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

                return successResponse;

            }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution via [this discussion](https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient/issues/223).

The problem was in the fact that I was using the ModernHTTPClint NuGet package, as seen in this line of the SubmitImage method:

```
using (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()))
```

The `NativeMessageHandler()` is said to make connections work much faster, but apparently in some cases results in the PROTOCOL_ERROR I had encountered. By removing this part, I fixed the problem.